# Scraping data with php

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am a beginner in scraping and I am using PHP simple_html_dom to scrape data from a website. My current code is not displaying any results. Maybe I don't target proper html tag. Second thing is I need that if there are no results for searched query that code displays message: "Results not found" or something like that. Any help is appreciated.

Here are sample queries:

3lnhl2gc9br764854
1J4FF28SXXL550156

```
  <?php 



require "simple_html_dom.php";

$trazi=$_POST['trazi'];

  $url="http://lookupvin.com/check/";



$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,

            "VIN=$trazi");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);

    $html = str_get_html($server_output);

    foreach($html->find('p.nmar') as $element)

  echo $element->innerText();


?>

index.php
<form action="vin.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="trazi">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what is the POST trazi here?

Comment: sorry, updated the script

Comment: Can you figure it out?

Comment: what kind of value you input in trazi. post an example of it.

Comment: You can take this one for example: 1J4FF28SXXL550156

Comment: Have you tried printing the $server_output directly to confirm that it's well formatted HTML?

Comment: yes and it prints out entire html page. What i need is specific data like Brand: Jeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
    $trazi="1J4FF28SXXL550157";
    $url="http://lookupvin.com/check/";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "VIN=$trazi");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($server_output);
$items = $html->find('.nmar');

if(count($items)!=0) {
    foreach($items as $post) {
        echo $post->children(0);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Input";
}
```

found a better class online for better html parsing. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library--net-11856 you can download it from here.

the result what i received.
[image]

Comment: i've removed it and it still doesn't show anything. can you please check if html tag is properly set?

Comment: actually server returns some error.. if user triggers the same url from same ip.. something like this.. ERROR: Too many attempts. Please contact us in order to get access to the VIN decoder API.

Comment: Ok let's try another site where i have been actually able to pull results but i haven't managed to figure out how to print not found message if there is no reord for that query. I've updated the script.

Comment: Can you figure it out?

Comment: yup trying it.. but the new site excepts post requests.  trying with those aspects now..

Comment: yup.. finally succeeded to some extent at least.. check my edited answer.

Comment: so it now prints result not found if there are not matches?

Comment: did you use "simple_html_dom.php";?

Comment: It is working when you provide valid vin number. But what if user provides something like: ashdahjs. Then code should print: no results found.

Comment: So you need to give a condition there.. If count of items > 0 then print actual values, else display something to result what you entered was invalid. Getting!!!

Comment: i've tried this and it still doesn't print nothing found if query s invalid
 if (count($element) > 0){
  echo $element->innerText();
  }else{
  echo "nothing found";
  }

Comment: sorry.. didn't enclose code properly.. now you can check my edit.. its perfectly fine now.. solution concluded.. Regards.. :)

Comment: How can i break this into array and target each item precisely? For example $item[0] is vin number $item[1] is model name etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS parameters. The server responses to GET request, no need to do POST. you pass the parameter properly as part of the query string. 
Also check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php, this may help you check if your request was successful.

Comment: are you getting any response whatsoever? print the $server_output, check the error codes like this 
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

Comment: It seems that html tag is not properl set

Comment: let's ensure your selector works. instead of echo $element->innerText(); do smth like echo 'found'. if it works it should display 'found' several times. maybe 'table' element itself has no innertext, so you need to loop through its children.

Comment: it still prints out entire page. Can you run script on your machine to check it out? You need index.php to accpet $trazi and vin.php to preform search and print results.

Comment: `    foreach($html->find('table.table-striped') as $element)
    {
        foreach ($element->find('td') as $row)
        {
            echo $row->innerText();
        }
        break;    
    } ` sorry, not sure how to format. as I suspected, the table itself has no contents, only its children do. the break is because there are 4 tables with same class, you only need first.

Comment: it seems that vindecoderz.com is blocking incoming requests because of some api. can you please check with updated code how to return result not found if there is no record matching query?

Comment: it prints the same table for any VIN, even obviously fake one, perhaps you should check for Brand: Unknown, Model: Unknown or something. entering a value less than 16 crashes their server :)

Comment: vindecoderz. it was all for nothing though, I think they have some anti-scraping solution to force using their API (which is not free I think). still if it allows access, the code above should give you an idea of how to process the data they send.

Comment: i am trying with lookupvin now and i pull results successfully. Things is though i can't figure how to print message if no records have been found??

Comment: there can be two cases: a) http request failed for some reason, you can check it with curl_error and b) the site responded correctly but with something like 'sorry, the VIN you're looking for is invalid', in this case you should just compare the successful and failed pages, find some differences and look for them